# NUnit TestCase Expected Messages

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, nunit, testcase

So I want to be able to specify different Exception messages in the `TestCase` but have no idea how that is done

This is the original

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(SystemException), ExpectedMessage = "Holiday cannot start or end on a weekend or non-working day")]

public void AddHolidays_StartsInvlaid()
{}
```

This is it with TestCase

```
[TestCase("27/04/2025", "28/05/2025", "FullDay", "FullDay", ExpectedMessage = "Holiday cannot start or end on a weekend or non-working day")]
[ExpectedException(typeof(SystemException), ExpectedMessage)]

public void AddHolidays_Exceptions(string dateFrom, string dateTo, string fromPeriod, string toPeriod)
{}
```

The method works fine but I just want to be able to specify the exception message with NUnit `TestCase`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can, I would recommend moving away from `ExpectedException`. It is considered a bad practice because it can lead to false positives if code in your tests throws the same exception where you weren't expecting it. Because of this, `ExpectedException` has been removed from NUnit 3. Also, as you have found, `ExpectedException` is also not fully supported across all of the data driven attributes in NUnit.

Moving your code to `Assert.Throws` will solve your problem. You can pass in the expected message from the `TestCase` as a regular parameter. I will simplify for readability;

```
[TestCase("27/04/2025", "Holiday cannot start or end on a weekend or non-working day")]
public void AddHolidays_Exceptions(string date, string expectedMessage)
{
    Assert.That(() => ParseDate(date), Throws.ArgumentException.With.Message.EqualTo(expectedMessage));
}
```

Comment: I think your `Assert::Throws` overload with message takes the assertion failure display message rather than expected message: `/// <param name="message">The message that will be displayed on failure</param>` — so if the exception is thrown at all, it would pass with any message

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're continuing to use NUnit 2.x, just use the ExpectedException property of TestCaseAttribute.